# PHP code show the same code for everyone

Tags: php, mysql, database

I got a point system that's like when people login a code display the user's data from database. but i noticed a problem. everyone got the same number. i'm called admin in the table and i'm on te top in it. but when i change my number of points to 20 everybody els get 20. Not in the database they get 20 but only on the page it disaplay 20. the script are:

```
<?php
require("dbc.php");  
$id = 1; //id or primary key of the user whose point you want to display   
$query = mysql_query("select * from users where id = $id") or die(mysql_error());

while($array = mysql_fetch_array ($query)) {
    echo "{$array['points']}<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: This code should only return one row with the content for user with id #1. How do you get the other users?

Comment: i dont get the other users but the other users se's the same number. everybody is geting 40.

Comment: **Heads up!** Future versions of PHP are *deprecating and removing* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Comment: @Carl Jonathan Thorbjørnsen Yes, because you set the ID to search for to one (`$id = 1;`) on each page call. See the answers below on how to fix that.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that your using a fixed number for your id variable. What you need to do instead is use `$id= $_POST['variable_name']` or `$id=$_GET['variable_name']

For example if your getting your player from an html input such as a text box. Your html would be

```
<input type="text" name="fname">
```

Your id would be

```
$id= $_POST['fname'];
```

The $_GET[] is a little harder to explain. Watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RZPLTiNlx8c for information on  $_GET[]

Comment: i chaned the $id = 1; to $id = $_POST['points'] but then i get this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$query' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: Sometimes in programming, when you correct one error more errors will come. Try typing print_r($query); and tell me what result you get.

Comment: @Carl Jonathan Thorbjørnsen often in PHP you have to look for the error one statement before what was given as line number in the error message. Or just search for the given part in your code (`$query`).

Answer (score 1):

Try printing out the value of $id for those other users (as with the var_dump function) to check whether it's correct.

If that doesn't solve it, try walking through your code and at every place confirm that each variable has the value that you think it has.

Comment: i dint quit understand that. i'm very new to coding. could you edit the code?

Comment: He is saying type the code var_dump($id); and tell what value shows up in your browser.

Answer (score 1):

The line `$id = 1; //id or primary key of the user whose point you want to display` doesn't make sence.
The [PRIMARY KEY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-primary-keys.html)  uniquely identifies each record in a database table.Each table can have only ONE primary key and it must contain unique values but cannot contain NULL values. For fast query performance each table should have a primary key.

This means that each user should have his own unique id.

The following code uses  the mysql_ extention which is deprecated you should use  MySQLi or PDO_MySQL

```
<?php
require("dbc.php");  
$id =  ;// $_POST or $_GET
$query = mysql_query("select * from users where id = $id") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
echo $row[0]; //Assuming 0 is id 

?>
```